# Существует ли хотя бы теоретическая возможность запустить BSD в Linux или Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bsd

Существует ли хотя бы теоретическая возможность запуска Unix (BSD, macOS) в посторонней ОС (Windows, Linux) (виртуальные машины не в счёт)?

Смотрите, что меня смутило. Linux запустили под Windows (WSL, WSL2, WSA), BSD (Linuxulator). Разве что под macOS не запустили... И если WSL2 - это чистый HyperV, в котором запущен урезанный Linux дистрибутив, то WSL1 - это прослойка с модифицированным ядром Linux. Что-то типа Wine, только наоборот и пошире, даже с поддержкой неродных для Windows файловых систем (даже виртуальных). Аналогично с Linuxulator, хотя BSD я лишь несколько раз тыкал.

И, казалось бы. Если уж Linux так смогли запустить, что мешает подобным образом запустить похожую и все также открытую BSD? Чёрт бы с Windows в силу её проприетарности (хотя вот есть wine, в Linux и Unix программы для Windows можно запустить некоторые). Проблема только в крайней непопулярности подобного технического решения или же есть принципиальные проблемы реализации подобных механизмов?

Comment: imho технических проблем тут нет (тем более, что сорсы обеих систем доступны). Наверное, просто никому это не интересно (и не понятно, кто будет благодарным пользователем такой системы). Кстати, когда-то в конце 80-х (еще до появления Linux) была версия [Domain/OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain/OS), которая содержала в себе API сразу 3-х систем -- AEGIS, System V Unix, и BSD Unix.

Comment: от бсд нужен рантайм или трансляция апи ядра?

Comment: Можно рассмотреть оба варианта.